# Java Chat: Cliente no recibe respuestas del servidor

Tags: java, servidor

Tengo un código en Java que es un chat.

El propósito del código es que un cliente se conecte, el servidor sepa que cliente está conectado y mandar un aviso a todos los clientes informando de quien esta conectado pudiendo luego empezar a chatear con los clientes que están conectados.

El primer cliente que se conecta  manda los mensajes al servidor, del servidor al segundo cliente y el segundo cliente recibe el mensaje.

Cuando el segundo cliente manda un mensaje también lo envía al servidor y el servidor lo envía al primer cliente.

**El problema es que el primer cliente no recibe el mensaje del segundo cliente.**

Aquí les dejo mi código a ver si alguien me puede ayudar con esto:

Cliente:

```
public class PageFrameClient extends JPanel implements Runnable{


    private JTextField field1;
    private JLabel nick;
    private JComboBox<String> ip;
    private JTextArea fieldchat;
    private static int n_ip=0;
    private JButton mybutton;


    public PageFrameClient(){ 

    //------------MAKE THE CHAT FRAME-----------------
        String nick_user=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nick Name: ");
        JLabel n_nick=new JLabel("Nick: ");
        add(n_nick);
        nick=new JLabel();
        nick.setText(nick_user);
        add(nick);

        JLabel text=new JLabel(" Online: ");
        add(text);

        ip=new JComboBox();

            add(ip);
        fieldchat=new JTextArea(12,20);
            add(fieldchat);

        field1=new JTextField(20);
            add(field1);        

        mybutton=new JButton("Send");
    //-------------------------------------------

        SendText myevent=new SendText(field1,nick,ip,fieldchat);//esta clase es cuando aprietan el boton Enviar el crea concecion con el servidor para enviar mensages

        mybutton.addActionListener(myevent);//Button to send all the data
        add(mybutton);  

        Thread thread=new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {//este hilo es para reecivir respuestas del servidor
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            ServerSocket s_client=new ServerSocket(9090);


            SendPackage recivePackage;


            while(true) {
                //-------------STREAM FROM SERVER TO CLIENT---------------

                Socket client=s_client.accept();
                fieldchat.append("\nIs Accepted");
                ObjectInputStream entryStream=new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

                recivePackage=(SendPackage) entryStream.readObject();
                fieldchat.append("\n Recive the msg");
                //-------------RECIVE THE MESSAGE---------------
                if(!recivePackage.getMessage().equals(" online")) {

                    fieldchat.append("\n"+ recivePackage.getNick() + ": "+ recivePackage.getMessage());

                }   
                //----------------------------------------------
                else {

                //---------ADD IPS TO COMBOBOX------------
                ArrayList<String>MenuIps=new ArrayList<String>();
                MenuIps=recivePackage.getIps();
                ip.removeAllItems();
                for(String z:MenuIps) {
                    ip.addItem(z);
                //----------------------------------------  


                fieldchat.append("\n"+ recivePackage.getIps().get(n_ip) +" Online");
                n_ip ++;}
                fieldchat.append("\n Ready to Close");



                }
                //-------------------------------------------------------

            }

        }catch(Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Clase que envia texto al servidor:

```
    public class SendText   implements ActionListener  {
    private JTextField field1;
    private JComboBox ip;
    private JLabel nick;
    private JTextArea fieldchat;
    private InetAddress address ;
    public SendText(JTextField _field,JLabel _nick,JComboBox _ip,JTextArea _fieldchat) {
        this.field1=_field;
        this.nick=_nick;
        this.ip=_ip;
        this.fieldchat=_fieldchat;
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fieldchat.append("\n You: "+ field1.getText());


        try {
            //--------SEND PACKAGE NICK , IP , MESSAGE TO SERVER-----------

            Socket mysocket=new Socket("10.0.11.14",1500);//ip of server
             System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            SendPackage data =new SendPackage();

            data.setNick(nick.getText());
            data.setIp(ip.getSelectedItem().toString());
            data.setMessage(field1.getText());

            ObjectOutputStream data_package=new ObjectOutputStream(mysocket.getOutputStream());

            data_package.writeObject(data);

            mysocket.close();

            //------------------------------------------------------------------    
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());    
}
    }


}
```

Servidor:

```
public class FrameServer extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    private JTextArea textarea;
    public FrameServer() {
        setBounds(1200,300,280,350);                

        JPanel mypage= new JPanel();

        mypage.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        textarea=new JTextArea();

        mypage.add(textarea,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(mypage);

        setVisible(true);


        Thread thread1=new Thread(this);
        thread1.start();

    }
    @Override
    public void run() {//Recive los mensages de los clientes
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(1500);
            String nick,ip,message;

            ArrayList<String>listIp=new ArrayList<String>();

            SendPackage recive_package=new SendPackage();

            while(true) {


                Socket mysocket=server.accept();


            ObjectInputStream data_package=new ObjectInputStream(mysocket.getInputStream());

                recive_package=(SendPackage) data_package.readObject();

                nick=recive_package.getNick();
                ip=recive_package.getIp();
                message=recive_package.getMessage();

                if(!message.equals(" online")) {


                textarea.append("\n"+ nick +" send: '"+ message +"'  to: "+ ip);

                Socket sendRecipient=new Socket (ip,9090);//encia mensages al destinatario
                ObjectOutputStream resendPackage =new ObjectOutputStream(sendRecipient.getOutputStream());
                resendPackage.writeObject(recive_package);
                System.out.println("Send The msg to ip :" + ip);
                resendPackage.close();
                sendRecipient.close();
                mysocket.close();       }   else {

                    //----------------DETECT ONLINE-------------------

                    InetAddress locate=mysocket.getInetAddress();
                    System.out.println("Inet:"+mysocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+" Local: "+ mysocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress());
                    String RemoteIp=  locate.getHostAddress();
                    System.out.println("Online "+ RemoteIp);
                    listIp.add(RemoteIp);
                    recive_package.setIps(listIp);

                    for(String z:listIp) {
                        System.out.println(z);
                        Socket sendRecipient=new Socket (z,9090);

                        ObjectOutputStream resendPackage =new ObjectOutputStream(sendRecipient.getOutputStream());
                        resendPackage.writeObject(recive_package);

                        resendPackage.close();
                        sendRecipient.close();
                        mysocket.close();
                    }

                    //-------------------------------------------------
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Cuál es el codigo de la clase `SendPackage`?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "el servidor envía un mensaje"? Si realmente es una conexión desde el servidor al cliente, hay una gran cantidad de cuestiones sobre la configuración de la red (firewalls, NATs, etc.) que pueden impedir esta comunicación. De hecho, normalmente los clientes son clientes "puros" y no reciben mensajes; se informan de las actualizaciones porque van haciendo peticiones al servidor (*polling*) y el servidor les devuelve la nueva información en la respuesta a esas peticiones.

Comment: el servidor recive el un paquete del remitente que lleva adentro : mensage,ip destinatario y el nick del remintente,  luego el servidor envia el mensage al ip destinatario

Comment: @alex55132 la clase SendPackage es una clase que contienen los datos (ip destinatario, mensaje y nick del remitente) que serian enviado al servidor para que el servidor sepa cual es el mensage de quien es y para quien es.